# Issue with Login/Logout funcationality

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hello good morning friends,

I am working for the application that required `login/logout` funcationality. Here I have login success,After that logout also work perfect but when I try for `again login` into the application that give me `406 status code`. here I am using `sharedpreference`s for the login/logout funcationality.

But when I `restart the application` it works random means it may sometimes login or sometimes not. But when `close the emulator` again start then works perfect.

Login.java

> please check the `onPostExecute()` method for below code

```
  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String loginURL = "http://www.cheerfoolz.com/rest/user/login";

            strResponse = util.makeWebCall(loginURL, uName, Password);

              try {
                JSONObject jsonSession = new JSONObject(strResponse);

                session = new SessionID();
                SessionID.sessionId = jsonSession.getString("sessid");
                SessionID.sessionName = jsonSession.getString("session_name");

                JSONObject jsonuser=jsonSession.getJSONObject("user");
                SessionID.userID = jsonuser.getInt("uid");


            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {
                if (strResponse.substring(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    txterror.setText("");

                    SharedPreferences userDetails =getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
                    edit.putString("username", uName);
                    edit.putString("password", Password);
                    edit.commit();


                } else {
                    txterror.setText("Username and Password Not valid !!!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
    }
```

Main.java

> In main class I have a logout button.

```
case R.id.home_btn_feature_logout:

        SessionID.setUserID(0);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.remove("username");
        editor.remove("password");
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        logout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        break;
```

Here I think session data is not clear properly, Plese let me know where I do mistake. And there is another solution for the login/logout then inform me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is anything wrong with your SharedPreferences API.I checked the Rest web service URL that you are using and its a Drupal site.You have to call user.logout to logout first.Since you are using REST try this.I havent tested this but it should work

```
String loginURL = "http://www.cheerfoolz.com/rest/user/logout";

strResponse = util.makeWebCall(loginURL,sessionid);
```

Also you might want to check if you have correctly configured your REST server endpoint.Check if you have enabled application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type of your REST service endpoint.Go to Server from Edit Resources in Services.Since it is working fine when login is called the first time I doubt this might be the problem.But still check it.

Comment: Please let us know which one of the 2 solutions solved it,since that might help some one having similar problem.Thanks.

Comment: currently I am using the first solution and it's working fine,I am not try for the second solution.

Comment: Here I am passing the usrId instad of the sessionID